# How do I change description name, if a different category is chosen?

Tags: php

I am trying to make a small webstore project, for the page `create_product.php` I am having it display the name, price and the description(which is three sub-categories - size, weight, and length), and then you can choose the category, for example I choose the category - book, I want the description to change to weight, if I change it to electronics i want it to change to size and so on.

Here is my create_product.php

```
<?php
// include database and object files
include_once 'config/database.php';
include_once 'objects/product.php';
include_once 'objects/category.php';

// get database connection
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

// pass connection to objects
$product = new Product($db);
$category = new Category($db);

// set page headers
$page_title = "Create Product";
include_once "layout_header.php";

echo "<div class='right-button-margin'>";
    echo "<a href='index.php' class='btn btn-default pull-right'>Read Products</a>";
echo "</div>";

?>
<?php 
// if the form was submitted - PHP OOP CRUD Tutorial
if($_POST){

    // set product property values
    $product->name = $_POST['name'];
    $product->price = $_POST['price'];
    $product->description = $_POST['description'];
    $product->category_id = $_POST['category_id'];

    // create the product
    if($product->create()){
        echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>Product was created.</div>";
    }

    // if unable to create the product, tell the user
    else{
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Unable to create product.</div>";
    }
}
?>

<!-- HTML form for creating a product -->
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">

    <table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'>

        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='name' class='form-control' /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='price' class='form-control' /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <?php
            if($id==1):
            ?>
            <td>Size</td>
            <td><textarea name='description' class='form-control'></textarea></td>
            <?php
            else:

            ?>
            <td>Weight</td>
            <td><textarea name='description' class='form-control'></textarea></td>
            <?php
            endif

            ?>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Category</td>
            <td>
            <?php
// read the product categories from the database
$stmt = $category->read();

// put them in a select drop-down
echo "<select class='form-control' name='category_id'>";
    echo "<option>Select category...</option>";

    while ($row_category = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        extract($row_category);
        echo "<option value='{$id}'>{$name}</option>";
    }

echo "</select>";
?>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>
<?php

// footer
include_once "layout_footer.php";
?>
```

In the form I am trying to do like an if statement where if the category value is 1 the description changes to size

```
<!-- HTML form for creating a product -->
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">

    <table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'>

        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='name' class='form-control' /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='price' class='form-control' /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <?php
            if($id==1):
            ?>
            <td>Size</td>
            <td><textarea name='description' class='form-control'></textarea></td>
            <?php
            else:

            ?>
            <td>Weight</td>
            <td><textarea name='description' class='form-control'></textarea></td>
            <?php
            endif

            ?>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Category</td>
            <td>
            <?php
// read the product categories from the database
$stmt = $category->read();

// put them in a select drop-down
echo "<select class='form-control' name='category_id'>";
    echo "<option>Select category...</option>";

    while ($row_category = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        extract($row_category);
        echo "<option value='{$id}'>{$name}</option>";
    }

echo "</select>";
?>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>
<?php
```

WHat should I write so that the description changes with the change of category?

Comment: If you only whant to change the text, maybe use javascript for that. add an evenlistener on the category and then change the text of the description

Answer (score 0):

You should use Javascript, this is a solution using JQuery:

```
$( "select" ).change(function() {
  var id = $(this).next().next().val();
if($(id)==1){
 $("tr:nth-of-type(3)").append("<td>Size</td>
            <td><textarea name='description' class='form-control'></textarea></td>");}
else
{
$("tr:nth-of-type(3)").append("<td>Weight</td>
            <td><textarea name='description' class='form-control'></textarea></td>");}
});
```

You can add more classes to easily select the wanted element, then change the script upon.